# How can I change image positions after creating in loop and making them subviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

In my app I have several 'for' loops like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        cmMajorMarker = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        cmMajorMarker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, widthVar,heighVar);
        cmMajorMarker.center = CGPointMake(xVar,yVar);
        [self.scrollView addSubview:cmMajorMarker];
    }
```

(small edit: above code is significantly simplified, which is why it appears to do very little)

They all do what I want them to do, which is to repeat a little black marker every number of pixels.

My problem arises when I want to change the position of these markers. I simply want to swap the side of the screen their on.

I'm doing it in another method, but I thought I would just need to write the following code to change the position of 100 images created:

```
cmMajorMarker.center = CGPointMake(xVar2, yVar2);
```

I should have realised that this would only change the position of the last of the 100 images created, instead of all of them.

My question is **How can I change the position of all 100 images created in the loop?**

*Changing the loop to accommodate the solution would not be a problem.*

I want to avoid removing all the subviews and recreating them in the new position because as you might suspect, it takes some time for the images to be drawn. Removing all the subviews and recreating them for all the loops takes over a second and I need it to be a lot quicker than that (and to put a lot less strain on the device).

I'm completely stumped and desperately need some sleep. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an NSMutableArray as a instance variable to hold the markers and iterate over them later again:

```
NSMutableArray *markerContainer = [NSMutableArray new];
```

and then change your current code to

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    cmMajorMarker = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    cmMajorMarker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, widthVar,heighVar);
    cmMajorMarker.center = CGPointMake(xVar,yVar);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:cmMajorMarker];
    [markerContainer addObject:cmMajorMarker];
}
```

If you want to change the center of all of them you do the following:

```
for (UIImageView *marker in markerContainer) {
    marker.center = CGPointMake(xVar2, yVar2);
}
```

Note: Your current code actually sets *ALL* of the markers at the exact same position - is that intended or is there more code that you are just not showing yet? ;)

Comment: Perfect! Just what I need. I completely overlooked using an array. In response to your note, there's code I omitted as it wasn't very relevant to the question. It just cluttered it up. Thanks for your help :)